# ECDiffieHellman inherits from AsymmetricAlgorithm but doesn't implement ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm?

Tags: .net, cryptography, diffie-hellman, aescryptoserviceprovider

I'm trying to understand the cryptography implementation (the big picture) in .NET and its relation to CSP, like what asymmetric algorithms are available for CSP, so if I want to implement a solution that uses CSP, what options I have.
I read this in [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.icspasymmetricalgorithm?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> Classes that extend the AsymmetricAlgorithm class should implement the
> ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm interface to enumerate key container
> information using a CspKeyContainerInfo object, and to import and
> export Microsoft Cryptographic API (CAPI)-compatible key blobs.

but however, [`ECDiffieHellman`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellman?view=netframework-4.7.2), inherits from `AsymmetricAlgorithm` but doesn't implement `ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm`.